# I am getting this error when trying to install Cardano-Node

Tags: haskell, cabal, cardano

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of Win32-network)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0 (conflict: Win32-network =>
base>=4.5 && <4.13)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0,
base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0,
base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1,
base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0,
base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: Win32-network, base)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, Win32-network
```

I am doing cabal install cardano-node cardano-cli within my Linux/Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [this commit](https://github.com/input-output-hk/ouroboros-network/commit/a04a821335531a0e77d8fc5ad6e826925515f5f4) relaxes that constraint suitably. Looks like the `master` branch of the `cardano-node` repo already requests a commit later than that, so probably just updating that repo will get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

Install cardano-cli & cardano-node the easy way on Mac:

1. Download the daedaluswallet.io wallet and install.
2. nano ~/.zshrc
3. export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Daedalus\ Mainnet.app/Contents/MacOS
4. source ~/.zshrc